# Model association with custom table and key names

Tags: php, phpactiverecord

I'm using [php.activerecord](http://www.phpactiverecord.org), and I am trying to link two tables.

I have `contacts` and `contactCompanyLinks`.  Each contact can contain one or more rows in the link table.  The field names in the table don't follow any sensible convention, but I can't change it as it would break another app using the same table.

The primary key of `contacts` is called `contactID`, and the foreign key in `contactCompanyLinks` is called `inspectorID`.

php.activerecord makes way too many assumptions, and I can't figure out how to get it to link my tables together.

Here are my models:

`Contact.php`:

```
<?php
class Contact extends ActiveRecord\Model {
    static $primary_key = 'contactID';

    static $has_many = array(
        array(
            'contactCompanyLinks',
            'class_name' => 'ContactCompanyLink',
            'foreign_key' => 'inspectorID'
        )
    );
}
```

`ContactCompanyLink.php`:

```
<?php
class ContactCompanyLink extends ActiveRecord\Model {
    static $table_name = 'contactCompanyLinks';

    static $belongs_to = array(
        array('contact')
    );
}
```

This looks right, but when I tried to get a row, it's not working.  I did the following:

```
<?php
var_dump(Contact::find(1234)->contactcompanylinks);
```

All I got printed to the screen was `NULL`!  If I tried other properties like `contactcompanylink` or `ContactCompanyLink` or `ContactCompanyLinks`, I got an "undefined property" error.

`var_dump(Contact::find(1234)` works just fine.  It shows me the fields from the `contacts` table.

How do I tell php.activerecord to stop assuming things and listen to me when I try to tell it how to link 2 tables together?

Comment: You are saying it works just fine when you `var_dump` the `find` result. What happens when you store that result in a variable and run the `contactcompanylinks` function then? I assume nothing will change because of how PHP works, but I have ran into weirder stuff.

Comment: @Jelmer: That's a good thought, but it doesn't change anything.  And yeah `::find` by itself works fine, but only returns rows from `contacts`.

Comment: And what happens when you extend the array where you defined the `belongs_to` with the `foreign_key` of the Model to bind? I have never worked with ActiveRecord, but I know in CakePHP you can define the `foreign_key`. It looks like the same structure. Did you try that? Over here I see them do something like that. http://www.phpactiverecord.org/docs/ActiveRecord/Model

Comment: @Jelmer: It doesn't work regardless of where I put `foreign_key`.  I tried in both `has_many` and `belongs_to`. =(

Comment: I am sure you have doublechecked this stuff already, but are you willing to post the database data you are using? Including tablenames, columnnames and the records you are testing this with. And I am wondering, what do you get when you simply run the `Contact::find('all');`? Do you get anything that might seem right? (Ps. just trying to help brainstorming). I think you have tried a lot already :)

Comment: @Jelmer: `contacts` just contains info about the contact.  `firstName`, `lastName`, etc. `contactCompanyLinks` contains `inspectorID` ("foreign key"), `companyID` (linked company) and `masterID` (parent company).  I just noticed that `contactCompanyLinks` doesn't have a `PRIMARY` key, nor are the foreign keys actually defined in the structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The undefined property-error comes probably from your `ID`. `phpactiverecord` assumes, nay FORCES all properties to be lowercase.

This means that **all the fields** should be called lowercase. E.G., your keys should be `inspectorid` and `contactid`.

Not that this is the case for columns only. Class names (php classes) should obviously be the case they actually are, and so should table names.

I always explicitly define ALL elements of a connection to avoid that assumption problem. This means both connection will have all elements for me:

```
static $belongs_to = array(
  array('somename',
        'foreign_key'=>'someid',
        'primary_key'=>'id', 
        'class_name'=>'Models\\NameSpace\\YourModelClassName')
);
```

but also the same fields are needed for the `has_many`. The primary in the `belongs_to` is the id of the OTHER table, and the foreign key is the key in this table (and when I say key, I mean the column name). For the belongs to the foreign key is the key in the other table, and the primary key the key in this table.

Also, mind the double slashes for the namespace.

Comment: `The field names in the table don't follow any sensible convention, but I can't change it as it would break another app using the same table.` So what you are saying is: he has to change it? There is no such method as 'overruling' it by simply setting the key in the bind array?

Comment: No! Where do you read that? :D I'm saying you should define them in the array that makes the connection, _because_ they are different then assumed :). And you should make them lowercase in all calls en definitions in the code: this doesn't really matter as SQL isn't case-sensitive for columns anyway: this way no changes have to be made to the field names.

Comment: it was a quote from Rocket's opening post, not your response :) But okay, now I understand. Tnx :)

Comment: Dude! That's it!  Adding `primary_key` and `foreign_key` to *both* `has_many` AND `belongs_to` (and making sure the names were all lower case) fixed the problem!  It no longer NULL :-D