# has_many through using custom table and field names

Tags: php, phpactiverecord

I'm using [php.activerecord](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/), and I am trying to link tables together.  I'm not using *their* structure, but php.activerecord assumes I am, so it doesn't always work.  I'm trying to use it on an already made app, so I can't change the database.

I learned from my previous question - [Model association with custom table and key names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868791/model-association-with-custom-table-and-key-names) - that I need to be as explicit as possible with the `primary_key` and `foreign_key` fields.

I'm having issues now using [has_many through](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/projects/main/wiki/Associations#has_many_through).  I keep getting `NULL`, and I have no idea why.

So, here's a scenario: I have 3 tables, `contacts`, `contactPrefs`, and `preferences`.  Those tables are as follows

```
contacts
--------
contactID
name
status

contactPrefs
------------
contactID
prefID
prefValue

preferences
-----------
prefID
name
description
```

Each `contact` has multiple `contactPrefs`.  Each `contactPrefs` has one `preferences`.  I tried to use `has_many` to get this working, but it's not.  Here are my models:

`Contacts.php`:

```
<?php
class Contact extends ActiveRecord\Model {
    static $primary_key = 'contactID';

    static $has_many = array(
        array(
            'prefs',
            'foreign_key' => 'contactid',
            'primary_key' => 'contactid',
            'class_name' => 'ContactPref'
        ),
        array(
            'preferences',
            'foreign_key' => 'prefid',
            'primary_key' => 'prefid',
            'through' => 'prefs',
            'class_name' => 'Preference'
        )
    );
}
```

`ContactPref.php`:

```
<?php
class ContactPref extends ActiveRecord\Model {
    static $table_name = 'contactPrefs';

    static $belongs_to = array(
        array(
            'contact',
            'foreign_key' => 'contactid',
            'primary_key' => 'contactid'
        ),
        array(
            'preference',
            'foreign_key' => 'prefid',
            'primary_key' => 'prefid'
        )
    );
}
```

`Preference.php`:

```
<?php
class Preference extends ActiveRecord\Model {
    static $primary_key = 'prefID';

    static $has_many = array(
        array(
            'prefs',
            'foreign_key' => 'prefid',
            'primary_key' => 'prefid',
            'class_name' => 'ContactPref'
        )
    );
}
```

According to [the docs](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/projects/main/wiki/Associations#has_many_through), I now should be able to the following:

```
<?php
var_dump(Contact::find(1234)->preference);
```

I cannot.  I get `NULL`.  Oddly, I *can* do this:

```
<?php
var_dump(Contact::find(1234)->prefs[0]->preference);
```

That works correctly.  But, shouldn't I be able to access the `preference` object *directly* through the `contact` object?  Am I misunderstanding the docs (they aren't the greatest, in my opinion)?  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I read your question multiple times, it seems you are having a delusion on how you can access properties. _One_ contact => _many_ contact prefs. _One_ contact pref => _one_ preference. By this assumption, `Contact::find(1234)` leads to one contact with many prefs. You can't directly access `preference` you need to know which of his many contact prefs you are referring to. Meaning `->prefs[index]->preference`. Which is what you already know. What you can do is make a specific `__get()` for preference, which would lead to **->prefs[0]->preference** always or just when you have one pref defined.

Comment: @Khez: I'm not totally sure how to use php.activerecord, I'm still new with it.  `Contact::find(1234)->prefs[0]->preference` works fine, as you notice, but in the [docs](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/projects/main/wiki/Associations#has_many_through), it seems you should be able to "directly" access `->preferences`.  The docs aren't very good, so I'm not sure if I'm interpreting them correctly.

Comment: the docs specifically say you can use `$order->users` ( an array of User object) which in your case is `Contact::finc(1234)->prefs` ( an array of Prefs object). You can select a specific pref object from that array by it's index (0 in your example) and then get that uniquely one-to-one identified preference, by doing prefs[0]->preference. Unfortunately for you, you're doing everything right, what you specifically want is either a hack / special case, or impossible. Do you expect Contact::find(1234)->preference, to give you an array of Preference objects?

Comment: @Khez: The thing is `Contact::find(1234)->prefs[0]->preference` works *without* the `though`.  I'm trying to understand the point of `through`, and I don't think I do.

Comment: Had to do a little bit of checking, I'm uncertain why without through works. Possibly because you are giving explicit foreign key relations. But! Checking the [Unit Tests](https://raw.github.com/kla/php-activerecord/master/test/RelationshipTest.php) for active record, you can see in **test_has_many_through** what behavior is expected. The one you are actually experiencing. I'm going to post an answer on how you can get a different behavior with this scenario in a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you are reading the docs with a small flaw. In the docs you are shown:

```
$order = Order::first();
# direct access to users
print_r($order->users); # will print an array of User object
```

Which you are already doing via `Contact::find(1234)->prefs`. Let me boil it down a bit

```
$contact = Contact::find(1234);
# direct access to prefs
print_r($contact->prefs); # will print an array of ContactPref object
```

Second, what you actually want is **undefined**. What should `Contact::find(1234)->preference` actually **do**? Return the preference of the first *ContactPref*? Return an array of *Preference* objects?

I feel like offering both:

```
<?php
class Contact extends ActiveRecord\Model {
    static $primary_key = 'contactID';

    static $has_many = array(
        array(
            'prefs',
            'foreign_key' => 'contactid',
            'primary_key' => 'contactid',
            'class_name' => 'ContactPref'
        ),
        array(
            'preferences',
            'foreign_key' => 'prefid',
            'primary_key' => 'prefid',
            'through' => 'prefs',
            'class_name' => 'Preference'
        )
    );

    public function get_preference() {
        return isset($this->prefs[0])
            ? $this->prefs[0]->preference
            : null
        ;
    }
    public function get_preferences() {
        $preference=array();
        foreach($this->prefs as $pref) {
            $preference[]=$pref;
        }
        return $preference;
    }
}
```

Let me explain a little bit what I have done. The **ActiveRecord\Model** class has a **__*get($name)*** function that looks for another function called **get_$name**, where **$name** in your case is **preference** (for the first result) and **preference** (for the entire collection). This means you can do `Contact::find(1234)->preference` which would be the same as doing `Contact::find(1234)->prefs[0]->preference` (but safer, due to the check) and `Contact::find(1234)->preferences` to get the entire collection of preferences.

This can be made better or optimized in numerous ways, so please don't take it as it is, but do try and adapt it to your specific situation.
For example you can either use the id of the preference as an index in the array or either  not force a load of more data from *ContactPrefs* than the ones you are going to use and try a more intricate query to get the preference objects that you specifically need.

If I find a better implementation by getting **through** to work in the relationship definition, I'll return. But seeing the [Unit Tests](https://raw.github.com/kla/php-activerecord/master/test/RelationshipTest.php) for active record, I'm skeptical.

Comment: In the docs why does `$order->users` work?  Why isn't it `$order->payments[0]->user`?  That's where I am confused.  I want `Contact::find(1234)->preferences` to give me an array of `Preference` objects, like how `$order->users` in the docs gives an array of `User` objects.  The docs are very confusing about what `through` actually does.

Comment: I've asked around, it seems it should be doing what you want it to do. It's possible directly forcing the key relations is somehow making it fail. Going to do some tests when I have some time. P.S. Ty for the edit :D

Comment: I think the main problem is: I am trying to do this on a already made database, so it doesn't follow their schema requirements.  Also, I guess I was a little confused at the docs.  `Contact::find(1234)->prefs[0]->preference` gets me exactly what I want.  Also, thanks for taking the time to help me out :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that look strange, so it's not easy to come to a "this will fix it" for you, but this is an issue at least:

Fieldnames should always be lower-case in phpactiverecord. SQL doesn't mind it either way (not that table names ARE case-sensitive, but column names aren't). So make this:

```
static $primary_key = 'contactID';
```

into

```
static $primary_key = 'contactid';
```

The connections // find commands can be used in SQL, in which case it doesn't really matter how your key-string is 'cased', so some stuff works. But if the connection goes trough the inner-workings of phpmyadmin, it will fail. So check out this `contactID` but also the `prefID`.

Again, this goes only for COLUMN names, so don't go changing classnames or table-names to lowercase.

*(extra point: phpmyadmin has trouble with combined primary keys. So while it might be ugly, you could add an extra row to your contactprefs table (if you don't allready have it) called `id`, to make that table actually have something to work with. It wouldn't give you much trouble, and it would help the activerecord library a lot)*

Comment: php.activerecord's assumptions do make things challenging when working with an existing database.  Changing the case of `$primary_key` didn't seem to change anything, nor did adding a `rowID` to `contactPrefs`.  I can get `contacts` and `contactPrefs` linked, and I can get `contactPrefs` and `preferences` linked, but I can't access `preferences` *through* `contacts`.  I have no idea if I'm using `through` right in my models.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<?php 
var_dump(Contact::find(1234)->preferences);
```

The documentation says that with a has_many relationship, it should be referenced by a plural (http://www.phpactiverecord.org/projects/main/wiki/Associations#has_many_through). The Contact::find(1234) returns a Contact object which has multiple contactPrefs with their each Preference. In addition, in your Contact model, you specify the has_many as **preferences** .

```
static $has_many = array(
    array(
        'prefs',
        'foreign_key' => 'contactid',
        'primary_key' => 'contactid',
        'class_name' => 'ContactPref'
    ),
    array(
        'preferences',
        'foreign_key' => 'prefid',
        'primary_key' => 'prefid',
        'through' => 'prefs',
        'class_name' => 'Preference'
    )
);
```

Edit Through Modification:

Try the following Contact model

```
<?php
class Contact extends ActiveRecord\Model {
static $primary_key = 'contactID';

static $has_many = array(
    array(
        'prefs',
        'foreign_key' => 'contactid',
        'class_name' => 'ContactPref'
    ),
    array('preferences', 
          'through' => 'prefs', 
          'class_name' => 'Preference',
          'primary_key' => 'prefID')
);
}
```

Comment: `Contact::find(1234)->preferences` returns NULL, and `Contact::find(1234)->preference` gives an "Undefined property" error.  For some reason, the `through` isn't linking correctly.

Comment: I thought the `foreign_key` and `primary_key` fields are what you joined on for that table.

Comment: I apologize, I misread the database schema. See updated model. The ContactPref table does not have a primary key according to the schema. Both contactid and prefid are foreign keys referencing the contact record and preference record respectively. The preferences table does not have a foreign key.